# Expect script not sending command

Tags: expect, u-boot

I am using expect to deal with an embedded system's U-boot.
However, my script is not sending command at certain point. 
Here is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set scriptaddr "0x32000000"

spawn screen /dev/ttyUSB1 115200
expect "Hit any key to stop autoboot:"
send "\r"
puts "Start flashing"
send "tftp $scriptaddr recovery_files/install.scr \r"
sleep 2
send "source 0x32000000\r"
## here start the flashing process which takes 15 mins

## this is the part where not working ##
expect "(Please reset your board)"
sleep 3
send "reset\r"
```

And this is the last part showing at the console which waiting user to key in "reset"

```
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         ###
         2 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 7333121 (6fe501 hex)
Uncompressed size: 168820224 = 0xA0FFE00

MMC write: dev # 0, block # 3940352, count 329727 ... 329727 blocks written: OK

============ INSTALLATION IS DONE =============
(Please reset your board)
machine#
```

Any mistake i have made? Please assist, thank you!

Comment: `expect -d` your script and see what's wrong.

Comment: @EmilyE. Ok thanks... I found expect timeout

Answer (score 1):

By default expect will have a 10seconds timeout. 
Solution : `set timeout <time in second>`